# Bootstrapping linux

Tags: linux-kernel, boot

I am trying to boot linux kernel by writing a boot loader myself, but dont know how to load the kernel.

All are saying to use *int 13h* to load sector from hard disk to memory.
Which **sector** should be loaded?? What to do after loading the sector?? 
Please share the code of a simple boot loader for the linux kernel if you can....

When searching for a boot loader, we can see only how to make the hello world bootloader, just to print **hello world** or asimilar message using assembly language.... nothing more can be seen...

What is kernel entry point??  Some says the start() function need to be called... but how??

Comment: "how to bootstrap linux" found [this](http://linuxgazette.net/issue70/ghosh.html), which looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

About the entry point:

In the Linux source code the file Documentation/x86/boot.txt is titled "The Linux/x86 Boot Protocol". It explains the current procedure for calling the kernel including the mode in which the CPU must be when booting and memory initialization.

About the disk sectors:

That file explains the booting process *after* you have loaded the compressed kernel from disk to memory. I suppose (but I'm not sure of it) that every bootloader has its own way to find the disk sectors corresponding to the kernel image and their second stage (512bytes of the MBR are usually not enough) and its own way to store those information.